# Error with JFrame size in Java

Tags: java, jframe

With my `JFrame` I did:

```
firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
firstFrame.setResizable(true);
firstFrame.setVisible(true);
firstFrame.setSize(1680, 1050);
firstFrame.pack();
```

but just appears a little window in the left-top corner with the exit, minimize and resize buttons. What should I do if I want that the window will appear with this size?

Comment: call pack before setting size

Comment: If we take a look at the [JavaDocs for `pack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()), it says *"Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method."* - This would suggest that you either don't have any content in your frame or that the content does not have a preferred size

Answer (score 3):

You need to call either `pack()` or `setSize` not both, if you decide to call `pack()` make sure that you have properly added components into your frame and/or that you set the preferred size of your frame using `setPreferredSize(Dimension)`

Comment: You don't need to call both, one or other depending on your needs, doing it this way, could make the window "appear" in two places at once